# Calling external activity by (explicit) intent from Qt app on Android - putExtra doesn't work

Tags: android, qt, android-activity, external

I have following problem:
On Android my Qt based app (Qt 5.4.1 for mobile) calls an external activity by starting an explicit intent. This works very well in case when no data are attached to the intent. But when I use putExtra to attach a string etc the destination activity doesn't find this data.

snippet of the Qt app:

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
if (activity.isValid())
{
    QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent", "()V");
    if (intent.isValid())
    {
        QAndroidJniObject action = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("test.app.DO_SOMETHING");
        if (action.isValid())
        {
            intent.callObjectMethod("setAction",
                                    "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;",
                                    action.object<jobject>());

            QAndroidJniObject subject = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("test_subject");
            QAndroidJniObject text = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("test_text");
            jint flag = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/content/Intent",
                                                                "FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION");

            intent.callObjectMethod("addFlags", "(I)V", flag);

            intent.callObjectMethod("putExtra",
                                    "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/string;)Landroid/content/Intent;",
                                    subject.object<jstring>(),
                                    text.object<jstring>());

            if (intent.isValid())
                activity.callObjectMethod("startActivity", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V", intent.object<jobject>());
        }
    }
}
```

snippet of the Java destination app, which tries to get the attached data:

```
public class Test_Activity extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String text = intent.getStringExtra("test_subject");//is null

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();//is null

        ...
    }
}
```

snippet of AndroidManifest.xml (destination Java app):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="test.app.DO_SOMETHING" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

I tried a while to get it running but it failed. What I'm doing wrong? Could it be missing permission or flag?

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

May be I am very late to Answer this Question, but thought may be helpful for somebody who is looking for same functionality. This code is working perfectly fine for me, I am able to receive data using Intent.

```
#include<QtAndroidExtras/QtAndroid>
#include<QtAndroidExtras/QAndroidJniObject>
#include<QtAndroidExtras/QAndroidIntent>
#include<QtAndroidExtras>

QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative",
                                                                       "activity",
                                                                       "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
if (activity.isValid())
{
    QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent", "()V");
    if (intent.isValid())
    {
        QAndroidJniObject action = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("test.app.DO_SOMETHING");
        if (action.isValid())
        {
            intent.callObjectMethod("setAction",
                                    "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;",
                                    action.object<jobject>());
            QAndroidJniObject subject = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("url");
            QAndroidJniObject text = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("http://www.google.com");


            intent.callObjectMethod("putExtra",
                                    "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;",
                                    subject.object(),
                                    text.object());

            if (intent.isValid())
                activity.callMethod<void>("startActivity", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V", intent.object<jobject>());
        }
    }
}
```

I made few changes in your code Using this Helpful [QT Android Blog](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/06/30/intents-with-qt-for-android-part-1/)

Answer (score -1):

You need to create class
class Picker : public QAndroidActivityResultReceiver
with function
void handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject &data) 
and start intent with
const int REQUEST_CODE = 42; QtAndroid::startActivity(intent, REQUEST_CODE, picker);

So, you can use my sample on github repo

https://github.com/tripolskypetr/qmlchooseimage